# Issue with Git rebase to master Saying Your branch is everything up to date

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I Try to rebase one of my branch to master repo It is always saying Your branch is everything up to date.

Is it bug or how do I fix this and how do I Rebase now.

And here is my commands to rebase

1. git checkout testbranch
2. git rebase master

Please help.

Comment: looks like you did the rebase and now your `testbranch` is up to date. you can verify with `git log` too see if a specific commit from the rebase is there.. it should be

Answer (score 0):

It seems your local master is still on old version and hence your testbranch is upto date with it.

You should pull latest master branch from remote (using `git pull` or `git fetch`) and make sure your local master is updated with remote master and then try to rebase.

Comment: Thanks @Rajni But I did same thing again and again still no luck